# jQuery, dynamically show table rows

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using a select form field with values of "10", "20", "30", how could you reveal / hide that number of tr rows in a table onchange of the dropdown?

Something like:

> $("#rows").change(function(){
>
> var num_rows = $(this).val();
>
> $("#data tr").reveal(num_rows) (???)
>
> });

**EDIT: rows should be added / removed starting from the bottom of the table.**

A sliding show / hide effect would be great.

Comment: What (x)html mark-up are you working with?

Comment: Can use any markup necessary, right now I just have an xhtml valid table with table, tbody, tr and td tags. No thead. Inside each cell is an img or span.

Comment: I can number the rows in a class attribute, that may be helpful

Comment: so apparently my solution before had a bug in it that chrome fixed (caught just now in ff) - fixed it, so give 'er a go :)

Answer (score 5):

I think this should work.

```
$("#rows").change(function(){

    var num_rows = $(this).val();

    $("#data tr").slice(num_rows).hide();

});
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit, David. This was my first post, and I wasn't aware of the formatting. Cheers.

Answer (score 5):

as kennis answered, use jQuery's `slice()` method.

I've put together a working example that you can try here: http://jsfiddle.net/a9TQ5/

**HTML Markup:**

```
<table id="mytable">
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>1</td></tr>
        <tr><td>2</td></tr>
        <tr><td>3</td></tr>
        ...
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**Javascript Code:**

```
function show (min, max) {
    var $table = $('#mytable'), // the table we are using
         $rows = $table.find('tbody tr'); // the rows we want to select
    min = min ? min - 1 : 0;
    max = max ? max : $rows.length;
    $rows.hide().slice(min, max).show(); // hide all rows, then show only the range we want
    return false;    
}
```

Using this function you are able to control the number of rows in `#mytable` by using these examples:

```
show(); // show all rows
show(1, 10); // show rows 1 - 10
show(1, 20); // show rows 1 - 20
show(3, 7); // show rows 3 - 7
show(20); // show rows 20 and up
```

You can bind this function to the change on a `<select>` like so:

**HTML:**

```
<select id="limit">
    <option value="0">None</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="15">15</option>
    <option value="20">20</option>
    <option value="" selected>All</option>
</select>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$('#limit').bind('change', function () {
    show(0, this.value);
});
```

Let me know if this is what you had in mind...

Answer (score 1):

So, I needed a break from work so I decided to throw this together (hopefully I read your question correctly ;)):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#rows').change(function(){
        if($('#tbl tr').length !== parseInt($(this).val()))
        {
            (u = function(){
                if($('#tbl tr').length < parseInt($('#rows').val()))
                {
                    var id = $('#tbl tr').length;
                    var e = $('#tbl').append('<tr style="display: none;" id="'+id+'"><td>foo</td></tr>');
                    $('#'+id).fadeIn('fast', function(){
                        if($('#tbl tr').length < parseInt($('#rows').val())) u();
                    });
                }
                else if($('#tbl tr').length > parseInt($('#rows').val()))
                {
                    var id = $('#tbl tr').length-1;
                    $('#tbl #'+id).fadeOut('fast', function(){
                        $(this).remove();
                        if($('#tbl tr').length >= parseInt($('#rows').val())) u();
                    });
                }
            })();
        }
    });
});
```

Using this, you can reveal/hide any number of rows in a table with nifty little tail calling fade in and outs.

*Of course, this was quickly hacked together and there's all kinds of optimizations that could be done.*

**[Fiddle sample here](http://jsfiddle.net/dbrecht/pfuGq/)**